# Using default value for a date parameter in metabase

Tags: mysql, parameters, default-value, sqlparameter, metabase

In metabase I want to have a query that gets two parameters of type date but if they are not provided uses some default values instead. This is an example of a between clause I used to achieve that but failed. It seems when no value is passed as parameter something other than null is set to variables in query.

```
BETWEEN COALESCE(date({{start_date}}),subdate(current_date, interval 1 month))
AND COALESCE(date({{end_date}}),subdate(current_date, 1))
```

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaymondNijland the whole query is irrelevant to my question. My problem is with using default values for sql parameters in metabase. This piece of query was shown just to give a better idea of what am I asking. I'm not looking for a solution for a specific query.

Comment: The link is mean to share your table structure and table data and expected results so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are right. But again my question has nothing to do with my data or any kind of specific table. Maybe I should edit it to represent what I mean better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this.
First I replaced the whole between clause with a field filter. Then I rewrote the whole query generated by metabase. For some strange reasons the query generated by metabase with lots of aliases could not be run by MariaDB driver I use.
Auto-generated query by metabase:

```
SELECT count(*) AS `count`, `orders`.`city` AS `city`, `orders`.`status` AS `status`, `orders`.`transport_type` AS `transport_type`,
date(`orders`.`launched_at`) AS `launched_at`
FROM `orders`
WHERE (date(`orders`.`deleted_at`) IS NULL
   AND {{filter_date}}
GROUP BY `orders`.`city`, `orders`.`status`, `orders`.`transport_type`, date(`orders`.`launched_at`)
ORDER BY `orders`.`city` ASC, `orders`.`status` ASC, `orders`.`transport_type` ASC, date(`orders`.`launched_at`) ASC
```

Then this question can be added to the dashboard. In dashboard edit mode filter widgets (or type date here) could be used to filter the question results. One thing that annoyed me is the dashboard has to be saved in order to have data in card refreshed.
This is my final query:

```
select count(*), orders.city, orders.status, orders.transport_type, date(orders.launched_at)
from orders
where (date(orders.deleted_at)) is NULL
        AND {{filter_date}}
GROUP BY orders.city, orders.status, orders.transport_type, date(orders.launched_at)
ORDER BY orders.city, orders.status, orders.transport_type, date(orders.launched_at)
```